# Change text with image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.lang-in-serach-blg').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('English','<img src="flags/24/en.png">');
});
```

I want to replace the text I want with an image, but this code displays the image URL instead of replacing the image. What should I do?

I also need this to work with multiple replacements. For example, I want to replace "English" with a flag, and later I want to replace "Francais" with another flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add `<img>` tags, you use must `.innerHTML`. You can simplify your code down to this:

```js
$('.lang-in-serach-blg').each(function() {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replaceAll('English', '<img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50">');
});

$('.lang-in-serach-blg').each(function() {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replaceAll('Francais', '<img src="https://placekitten.com/60/60">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="lang-in-serach-blg">
  English filler text filler text English.
</p>

<p class="lang-in-serach-blg">
  English filler text filler text English.
</p>

<p class="lang-in-serach-blg">
  Francais filler text filler text Francais.
</p>
```

If you're changing the content of the webpage after the DOM loads, then you should run this code again after the DOM is changed. If you were to use a framework that handles state for you (ie: React, Vue, Svelte, etc.), then the framework would handle this for you, but with pure jQuery you'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: I use this code in a site that has several pages and pages 2, 3, etc. are loaded in Ajax.
This code works fine when I open the site (first page), but when I load subsequent pages (in Ajax), the code stops working.
Do I need to change anything?

I start my code with: jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

Comment: @Pudy If you're dynamically changing the page's content, then you should run the code in my answer again. A simple way to do this would be to put all the code from my answer in a function. You can then call this function inside `jQuery(document).ready`, then again when you update the page.